# Что нужно прописать в PHP, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку обновлялась страница?

Tags: php

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку у меня обновлялась страница. Желательно, чтобы это была какая-нибудь команда на PHP.

Comment: Учите матчасть и разбирйтесь. Ссылка и так обновляет страницу (если она не якорная или не переопределяется js). Команда на PHP? Что?

Comment: да, php здесь не поможет, потому что он обрабатывается на стороне сервера, а перезагрузка страницы - на стороне клиента. Если просто, то js
`<a href="javascript:location.reload();">Перезагрузить</a>`